# TypeORM problem saving entity with cascade true

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I m using NestJS with TypeORM and I m trying to save a user conversation with messages. I set the messages field on the conversation entity to ***cascade: true***. But When I try this code:

```
const user3: User = { login: 'admin', createdBy: 'system', lastModifiedBy: 'system' };
const user4: User = { login: 'user', createdBy: 'system', lastModifiedBy: 'system' };
const message1: Message = { content: 'Hello How are you? ', createdBy: user3.login, lastModifiedBy: user3.login };
const conversation1: Conversation = { sender: user3, reciever: user4, messages: [message1] };
getConnection().getRepository(Conversation).save(conversation1);
```

It creates this query:

```
INSERT INTO "message"("id", "createdBy", "createdDate", "lastModifiedBy", "lastModifiedDate", "content", "conversationSenderId", "conversationRecieverId", "conversationDate") VALUES (?, ?, datetime('now'), ?, datetime('now'), ?, ?, ?, ?)
-- PARAMETERS: ["67348880-6897-47cb-92ef-5f66ffb2e88c","admin","admin","Hello How are you? ","b2420445-c8ee-4080-86b3-98ab12ef576b","09f3672d-9b2f-4f68-b47e-a7ca5d806ec6","2019-10-24 14:41:40.000"]
```

with this error:

```
{ [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed] errno: 19, code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT' }
```

I can see it's a problem with the foreign key of messages table but I can't fix it because it's TypeORM library which handle the creation, not me.
I searched on internet (documentation, github, stackoverflow) without success.
I think it's bug in TypeORM library but I m a novice in it so I prefer asking if I did something wrong

Here are my entities :

```
export abstract class BaseEntity {
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id?: string;

  @Column()
  createdBy?: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdDate?: Date;

  @Column()
  lastModifiedBy?: string;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  lastModifiedDate?: Date;
}

@Entity('user')
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  login?: string;

  @OneToMany(type => Conversation, conversation => conversation.sender)
  sentConversations?: Conversation[];

  @OneToMany(type => Conversation, conversation => conversation.reciever)
  recievedConversations?: Conversation[];
}

@Entity()
export class Conversation {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  senderId?: string;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  recieverId?: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ primary: true })
  date?: Date;

  @OneToMany(type => Message, message => message.conversation, { cascade: true })
  messages: Message[];

  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.sentConversations)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'senderId' })
  sender?: User;

  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.recievedConversations)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'recieverId' })
  reciever?: User;
}

@Entity('message')
export class Message extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ length: 10000 })
  content: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => Conversation, conversation => conversation.messages)
  conversation?: Conversation;
}
```

In this repository, you will be able to reproduce the bug: 
https://github.com/youtix/nest-typerorm-test

Comment: what is your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key constraint is on your database tables.  Cascade in RDBMS terms means its going to propagate through every relationship.  I believe your adminID on your creation isn't a user within your user table.  You need to query that user first then use it for the message push.  This should solve your problem man.

1. Select * from user where uname = 'admin'
2. Insert into message table where userId = (userId from 1)
3. celebrate

Answer (score 0):

I checked your git project, if you change `synchronize: false` in `orm.config.js` everything should work fine

Comment: Can you explain please why?

Comment: Here is link to doc https://typeorm.io/data-source-options