# Issue saving Entity through CASCADE with One-To-Many relationship

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

[Like this user's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58554432/typeorm-problem-saving-entity-with-cascade-true) I'm attempting to save an entity called `Project` with it's `Spaces` through a One-to-Many relationship (that is, one `Project` can have many `Spaces`) using TypeORM. I believe I've constructed the relationship correctly and the `sql` logging output even says it committed:

```
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO "project_model"("id", "name", "client", "tenancy", "units", "hasBroadcast", "hasLab", "createdBy", "modifiedBy", "dateCreated", "dateModified", "areaGross", "areaNet", "floors", "targetFactorCirculation", "targetFactorLoss", "targetAreaPerWorkseat", "targetNumOfWorkseats", "totalProgrammedArea", "totalWorkseatRatio", "totalNumOfWorkseats", "totalNumOfCollb 
seats", "totalCollaborationRatio") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23) RETURNING "dateCreated", "dateModified" -- PARAMETERS: ["ab58246e-f7dd-476d-9127-3ac3fc1c93c3","","Hardik2","Single","Metric",true,true,null,"","1605706917230","1605706917230","111","90","1","18","2","5","48","0","0","0","0","0"]query: UPDATE "space_model" SET "projectId" = $2 WHERE "id" = $1 -- PARAMETERS: ["ab58246e-f7dd-476d-9127-3ac3fc1c93c5","ab58246e-f7dd-476d-9127-3ac3fc1c93c3"]
query: COMMIT
```

but I never see the data in the `Spaces` table when I check in Postgres.

Given these two models:

```
@Entity()
class Project extends IProject {
    @OneToMany(type => Space, space => space.project)
    public spaces: Space[]
}
```

```
@Entity()
class Space extends ISpace {
    @ManyToOne(type => Project, (project) => project.spaces, {
    cascade: true
    })
    project: Project
}
```

And a simple repo that saves like this:

```
  async updateData(data: Partial<T>): Promise<T> {
    await this.getRepo();

    const dbObj = data as any;
    console.log(dbObj);
    const updated = await this.repo.save(dbObj);

    return updated;
  }
```

Can anyone think of reasons this might not work?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer after doing just a *little* more research. Basically, I needed to handle the cascade relationship better [as was pointed out in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55101273/1732184).

**The `cascade` option needs to be on the element that will handle the saving, not the element that might be saved.**

Changed `Project` to this:

```
@Entity()
class Project extends IProject {
   @OneToMany(type => SpaceModel, space => space.project, {cascade: true})
   spaces: Partial<SpaceModel>[];
}
```

and `Space` to this:

```
@Entity()
class Space extends ISpace {
  @ManyToOne(() => ProjectModel, 
    project => project.spaces, { 
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    }
  )
  @JoinColumn()
  project: ProjectModel;
}
```