# NestJS: TypeORM One to Many relation cascade update not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

Below is my DB design diagram -
[image: sports equipments]

Entities -

```
// Sports table entity
@Entity({name: 'Sports'})
export class Sports {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column()
  name!: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Tennis, (tennis) => tennis.sport, {cascade: true})
  tennis!: Tennis[];
}
```

```
// Tennis table entity
@Entity({name: 'Tennis'})
export class Tennis {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column()
  sportsId!: number

  @Column()
  racketBrand!: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Sports, (sport) => sport.tennis, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  sport!: Sports;
}
```

sports.service.ts

```
public async update(id: number, updateSportsDto: UpdateSportsDto) {
    return this.sportsRepository.save({id, ...updateSportsDto}).then(() => {
      return this.sportsRepository.findOneOrFail({
        where: {id},
        relations: ['sports', 'sports.tennis'],
      });
    });
  }
```

When I try to do a `PATCH /sports/:id` request to update records, I get following error message:

`"message": "null value in column \"sports_id\" of relation \"tennis\" violates not-null constraint",`

I am successfully able to perform cascade insert operation, but having trouble with cascade update.

There are couple of answers I referred, but those didn't help -

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55101273/10011503
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65012542/10011503

How do I make sure `sports_id` gets passed from `Sports` table to `Tennis` table?

Comment: For anyone who’s stuck with similar issue, I am using `QueryRunner` for now, to perform (multiple) table update operation as a part of transaction. You can find example here - https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/transactions#using-queryrunner-to-create-and-control-state-of-single-database-connection